# Swift updating UITableView with new data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

I'm trying to repopulate my `UITableView` with data from another JSON call.

However my current setup doesn't seem to work, and while there are many identical questions on SO the answers I could find I've already tried.

I'm saving my API data in `CoreData` entity objects. And I'm filling my UITableView with my `CoreData` entities.

In my current setup I have 3 different API Calls that has a different amount of data, and of course different values. I need to be able to switch between these 3 datasets, and that's what I'm trying to accomplish now. (so far without progress).

I have a function called "loadSuggestions", which is where I assume my fault lies.

- First I check for an internet connection.
- I set the managedObjectContext
- I check what API I need to call (This is determined before the function is called, and I checked that it works as intended)
- I delete all the current data from the entity that it's trying to call. (I also tried to delete the data from the last data the `UITableView` had loaded. That didn't change anything). I also checked that this works. After deleting the data, I checked that it prints out an empty array, I also tried logging the objects it deletes to make sure.
- I then fetch the new data, save it into temporary variables. Then save it to my core data.
- Then I make my second API call (dependant on a variable from the first one), fetch that data and save it the same way.
- I append the object to the array the `UITableView` fills it's cells from. (I checked that it prints out correctly as well)
- And lastly I reload the tableView. (doesn't change a thing)

Here's the function:

```
func loadSuggestions() {
    println("----- Loading Data -----")
    // Check for an internet connection.
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == false {
        println("ERROR: -> No Internet Connection <-")
    } else {
        // Set the managedContext again.
        managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

        // Check what API to get the data from
        if Formula == 0 {
            formulaEntity = "TrialFormulaStock"
            println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
            formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/entry_weekly.json")
        } else if Formula == 1 {
            formulaEntity = "ProFormulaStock"
            println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
            formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/entry_weekly.json")
        } else if Formula == 2 {
            formulaEntity = "PremiumFormulaStock"
            formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/proff_weekly.json")
            println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
        } else if Formula == 3 {
            formulaEntity = "PlatinumFormulaStock"
            println("Setting Entity: \(formulaEntity)")
            formulaAPI = NSURL(string: "http://api.com/json/fund_weekly.json")
        }

        // Delete all the current objects in the dataset
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: formulaEntity)
        let a = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as! [NSManagedObject]
        for mo in a {
            managedContext.deleteObject(mo)
        }

        // Removing them from the array
        stocks.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        // Saving the now empty context.
        managedContext.save(nil)

        // Set up a fetch request for the API data
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName(formulaEntity, inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: formulaAPI!)
        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
        var formula = JSON(data: data!)

        // Loop through the api data.
        for (index: String, actionable: JSON) in formula["actionable"] {

            // Save the data into temporary variables
            stockName = actionable["name"].stringValue
            ticker = actionable["ticker"].stringValue
            action = actionable["action"].stringValue
            suggestedPrice = actionable["suggested_price"].floatValue
            weight = actionable["percentage_weight"].floatValue

            // Set up CoreData for inserting a new object.
            let stock = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

            // Save the temporary variables into coreData
            stock.setValue(stockName, forKey: "name")
            stock.setValue(ticker, forKey: "ticker")
            stock.setValue(action, forKey: "action")
            stock.setValue(suggestedPrice, forKey: "suggestedPrice")
            stock.setValue(weight, forKey: "weight")

            // Get ready for second API call.
            var quoteAPI = NSURL(string: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/json?symbol=\(ticker)")

            // Second API fetch.
            var quoteRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: quoteAPI!)
            var quoteData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(quoteRequest, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
            if quoteData != nil {
                // Save the data from second API call to temporary variables
                var quote = JSON(data: quoteData!)
                betterStockName = quote["Name"].stringValue
                lastPrice = quote["LastPrice"].floatValue

                // The second API call doesn't always find something, so checking if it exists is important.
                if betterStockName != "" {
                    stock.setValue(betterStockName, forKey: "name")
                }

                // This can simply be set, because it will be 0 if not found.
                stock.setValue(lastPrice, forKey: "lastPrice")

            } else {
                println("ERROR ----------------- NO DATA for \(ticker) --------------")
            }

            // Error handling
            var error: NSError?
            if !managedContext.save(&error) {
                println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
            }
            // Append the object to the array. Which fills the UITableView
            stocks.append(stock)

        }

        // Reload the tableview with the new data.
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Currently, when I push to this viewController, this function is called in `viewDidAppear` like so:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    tableView.allowsSelection = true
    if isFirstTime {
        loadSuggestions()
        isFirstTime = false
    }
}
```

It populates the tableView correctly and everything seems to work as planned.

However if I open my slide-out menu and call a function to load different data, nothing happens, here's an example function:

```
func platinumFormulaTapGesture() {
    // Menu related actions
    selectView(platinumFormulaView)
    selectedMenuItem = 2
    // Setting the data to load
    Formula = 3
    // Sets the viewController. (this will mostly be the same ViewController)
    menuTabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
    // Set the new title
    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "PLATINUM FORMULA"
    // And here I call the loadSuggestions function again. (this does run)
    SuggestionsViewController().loadSuggestions()
}
```

Here's the 2 relevant tableView functions:

number of Rows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stocks.count
}
```

And cellForRowAtIndexPath, (this is where I set up my cells with the CoreData)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("com.mySuggestionsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! mySuggestionsCell

    let formulaStock = stocks[indexPath.row]
    cell.stockNameLabel.text = formulaStock.valueForKey("name") as! String!
    cell.tickerLabel.text = formulaStock.valueForKey("ticker") as! String!
    action = formulaStock.valueForKey("action") as! String!
    suggestedPrice = formulaStock.valueForKey("suggestedPrice") as! Float

    let suggestedPriceString = "Suggested Price\n$\(suggestedPrice.roundTo(2))" as NSString
    var suggestedAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: suggestedPriceString as String)

    suggestedAttributedString.addAttributes(GrayLatoRegularAttribute, range: suggestedPriceString.rangeOfString("Suggested Price\n"))
    suggestedAttributedString.addAttributes(BlueHalisRBoldAttribute, range: suggestedPriceString.rangeOfString("$\(suggestedPrice.roundTo(2))"))
    cell.suggestedPriceLabel.attributedText = suggestedAttributedString

    if action == "SELL" {
        cell.suggestionContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.formulaGreenColor()
    }

    if let lastPrice = formulaStock.valueForKey("lastPrice") as? Float {
        var lastPriceString = "Last Price\n$\(lastPrice.roundTo(2))" as NSString
        var lastAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: lastPriceString as String)

        lastAttributedString.addAttributes(GrayLatoRegularAttribute, range: lastPriceString.rangeOfString("Last Price\n"))

        percentDifference = ((lastPrice/suggestedPrice)*100.00)-100

        if percentDifference > 0 && action == "BUY" {
            lastAttributedString.addAttributes(RedHalisRBoldAttribute, range: lastPriceString.rangeOfString("$\(lastPrice.roundTo(2))"))
        } else if percentDifference <= 0 && percentDifference > -100 && action == "BUY" {
            lastAttributedString.addAttributes(GreenHalisRBoldAttribute, range: lastPriceString.rangeOfString("$\(lastPrice.roundTo(2))"))
        } else if percentDifference <= 0 && percentDifference > -100 && action == "SELL" {
            lastAttributedString.addAttributes(RedHalisRBoldAttribute, range: lastPriceString.rangeOfString("$\(lastPrice.roundTo(2))"))
        } else if percentDifference == -100 {
            lastPriceString = "Last Price\nN/A" as NSString
            lastAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: lastPriceString as String)

            lastAttributedString.addAttributes(GrayLatoRegularAttribute, range: lastPriceString.rangeOfString("Last Price\n"))
            lastAttributedString.addAttributes(BlackHalisRBoldAttribute, range: lastPriceString.rangeOfString("N/A"))
        }

        cell.lastPriceLabel.attributedText = lastAttributedString
    } else {
        println("lastPrice nil")
    }

    weight = formulaStock.valueForKey("weight") as! Float
    cell.circleChart.percentFill = weight
    let circleChartString = "\(weight.roundTo(2))%\nWEIGHT" as NSString
    var circleChartAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: circleChartString as String)
    circleChartAttributedString.addAttributes(BlueMediumHalisRBoldAttribute, range: circleChartString.rangeOfString("\(weight.roundTo(2))%\n"))
    circleChartAttributedString.addAttributes(BlackSmallHalisRBoldAttribute, range: circleChartString.rangeOfString("WEIGHT"))
    cell.circleChartLabel.attributedText = circleChartAttributedString

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}
```

I define my appDelegate as the very first thing in my class:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
var managedContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
```

I think that's all the code that could possibly be the cause of the bug. Again I think the most likely cause would be in the `loadSuggestions` function.

To force update the tableView I also tried calling `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsLayout` both on `self.view` and `tableView`, neither of which seemed to do anything at all.

Any advice in figuring out why this tableView refuses to update would be an enormous help!

And I apologize for the walls of code, but I havn't been able to find the exact origin of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in the platinumFormulaTapGesture function is incorrect,

```
SuggestionsViewController().loadSuggestions()
```

This creates a new instance of SuggestionsViewController, which is not the one you have on screen. You need to get a pointer to the one you have. How you do that depends on your controller hierarchy, which you haven't explained fully enough.

Comment: Thanks!, (still havn't figured out how to fix it. But I wasn't aware of that). For my controller hierarchy. I have a `ContainerViewController`. (with 2 `childViewControllers`), one of those is a slide-out menu, the other is a `UITabBarController`, where this page is one of the `UITabBarController`'s `UIViewControllers`.

Comment: @MarkL What page is one of the tab bar controller's view controllers? SuggestionsViewController? Which controller is the platinumFormulaTapGesture function in?

Comment: the "page" with the `UITableView` causing issues, is called `suggestionsViewController`. (the first `UIViewController` in my `UITabBarController`). The `platinumFormulaTapGesture` function is in my `sidePanelViewController`, which is my menu viewcontroller.

Comment: @MarkL Are you using a storyboard to create your controllers? Did you add container views to your ContainerViewController. If so, you can get a pointer to the two children by using prepareForSegue. Once you have those 2 pointers, you can set SuggestionsViewController (tabBarController.viewControllers[0]) as the delegate of SidePanelViewController. SidePanelViewController would define the protocol, and call its delegate method in the platinumFormulaTapGesture function. In its implementation of the delegate method, SuggestionsViewController would call its loadSuggestions function.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not using storyboards, and I don't have any "pointers".

Comment: @MarkL How and where are you creating the controllers then? When you create them, you do have pointer to them.

Comment: I push the ContainerViewController, from either my loginViewController or my SignUpViewcontroller. (it's pushed to the navigation stack of my NavigationController). It's 2 childViewControllers are created on viewDidLoad I believe.

Comment: @MarkL Then you have pointers (variables or properties) to them in viewDidLoad.

Comment: sorry for the slow replies. Been a busy few days. Do you know of a place where I can read up on how to use pointers to run the function for the class Intended, instead of creating a new instance of it?

Comment: @MarkL, no I don't.  When I say "pointer", I'm just talking about the variable you assign an instance to. So, if you create a controller with `var tbc = UITabBarController()`, then tbc is a pointer to that instance you created. If you want to access the controller in the first tab, then you would use tbc.viewControllers[0].

Comment: Ahh I see, I was looking into C Pointers there for a moment -.-". My UITabBarMenuController, is called "menuTabBarController". However, doing `menuTabBarController.viewControllers[0]` causes the error: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]?' with an index of type 'Int' `

Comment: @MarkL, you probably need a downcast: (menuTabBarController.viewControllers as! [UIViewcontroller])[0]

Comment: That results in a similar error: `Cannot subscript a value of type '([UIViewController]?)' with an index of type 'Int'`. Tried removing the array around UIViewController. Same error.

Comment: also tried calling like so: `ContainerViewController().tabBarController!.viewControllers[0] as! SuggestionsViewController` and `menuTabBarController!.viewControllers[0] as! SuggestionsViewController`. But gives the same errors as above.

Comment: @MarkL, It should be with a "!", not a "?". I tested this, `(menuTabBarController.viewControllers as! [UIViewcontroller])[0]`, and it compiled successfully. Anyway, these questions about Swift syntax should be a new question if you continue to have problems with them.

Comment: great! doesn't return any errors anymore. But I can't seem to access the function `loadSuggestions()`. But you're right. This has gone quite far from my original question. I'll make a new one.