# Swift accessing a function of a viewController through a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, function, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a tableView I need to update. As explained in another question here: [Swift updating UITableView with new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660543/swift-updating-uitableview-with-new-data/29661086#29661086)

Anyhow. The right answer ended up being completely unrelated to my original question, and I was suggested making another question on how to call the function for the specific viewController I need to call it in.

Here's my Controller setup.

```
NavigationController
   ContainerViewController. (2 childViewControllers)
      menuTabBarController (this is a UITabBarController)
         SuggestionsViewController (This is the viewController I need to run a function from)
         ...
      SideBarViewController
```

The viewController that has the `UITableView` is the `suggestionsViewController`.

The viewController I need to run the function from is the `SideBarViewController`.

The function I am trying to call is called `loadSuggestions()`

My first try was of course just running:

```
SuggestionsViewController().loadSuggestions()
```

However as explained in my other question. This creates a new instance of it, rather than running `loadSuggestions()` on the viewController where I want to update my `UITableView`

The user (rdelmar) that helped deduce the problem of why the UITableView wasn't updated, pointed me in the /right/ direction and I got the following code working:

```
(menuTabBarController.viewControllers as! [UIViewController])[0]
```

However. My current issue, is that I can't access `loadSuggestions()` from that

So. In short. I need to update my `UITableView` using the function `loadSuggestions()` when I tap a button on my slide-out menu.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `(menuTabBarController.viewControllers as! [UIViewController])[0]` is the correct view controller, you can cast that `as SuggestionsViewController` and you'll be able to call the method as long as it's not a private method.

You can't call the method with what you have because you're getting an array of `UIViewController`, and `UIViewController` doesn't have the `loadSuggestions` method.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Been at this for days. Massive help. Can't accept it for another 3 minutes though. Thank you!!!!!